# Debuging issue with maven, jetty and IDEA

Tags: debugging, maven-2, intellij-idea, jetty

I have problem with running jetty in debug and attaching IntelliJ IDEA to listening port.

`mvnDebug jetty:run-exploded`

will start jetty as I can see following message

> Preparing to Execute Maven in Debug
>   Mode Listening for transport dt_socket
>   at address: 8000

However when I try to to connect IDEA to port 8000 I will get message in IDE saying connected and immediately followed by disconnected. Where jetty will kick following error

> Exception in thread "main"
>   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org/codehaus/classworlds/Launcher
>   Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native
>   Method)   at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
>     at
>   sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
>     at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:320)
>   Could not find the main class:
>   org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher. 
>   Program will exit.

I'm little confused by this as there is no problem in running project under jetty with

`mvn jetty:run-exploded`

also my colleague have no problem with debugging under IDEA, only difference between his and my setup is that I have 64bit machine and he is on 32bit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found temporary solution for debug.

Before executing I just re-export MAVEN_OPTS with some additional parameters so this will work only on currently open terminal window.

My system MAVEN_OPTS are
`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx512m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit"`

and session changed to 
`export MAVEN_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx1500m -XX:PermSize=128m -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=8000,server=y,suspend=n"`

I will have to discuss "mvnDebug" alias set-up with my colleague when he gets back tomorrow...

Comment: This seems to be a general bug in mvnDebug